# How to change paragraph background-color in css after click on link in html page

Tags: html, css

Can I change background color of paragraph when I click on a link in the page.

> ```
> <a href="#p4">Go to P4</a>
>
> <p id="p4">I'm P4</p>
> ```

what I need write in css to get -

> p {   background-color: yellow; }

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the attribute of an element by clicking on another element with CSS, but it can be with JavaScript. Just add `<script>` tag to end of your `<body>` and `onclick()` to `<a>`:

```html
<body>
    <a href="#p4" onclick="changeColor()">Go to P4</a>
    <p id="p4">I'm P4</p>

    <script>
      function changeColor() {
      document.getElementById("p4").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      }
    </script>
</body>
```